# Bevel causing ripples

Tags: bevel

[image]I've got a bevelled shape, but the ngon on top then has ripples from the bevel. I know this is something to do with the ngon, but unsure how to best link up vertices to fix the ripples. Is there a usual way to fix?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Hello please show your wireframe, maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots thanks, I've added a pic of the wireframe — I can't remember how to add the link to the blender file, does this screenshot help? Thank you

Comment: you can share it with https://blend-exchange.com/ (follow the instructions)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qV4AnBbE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qV4AnBbE/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a big ngon, and as you've shaded smooth, Blender is trying to smooth between the small faces on the side and this big ngon, which will show the inner triangles:

[image]

To avoid that you can select all the top faces and inset. This way the ngons will now be co-planar with their new adjacent faces, and Blender won't try to smooth between these co-planar faces:

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks @moonboots — this is a big help. I'd actually tried that but just with the single face adjacent to the bevel. Did I set this up correctly or would it have been better not to use the bevel in the first place? Still trying to figure out optimal ways to build things. Thanks again, really appreciate it

Comment: This topology is OK, ngons are OK as long as they are not noticeable